# Calculating area in km² for Polygon in WKT using Python

Tags: python, polygon, shapely, area, well-known-text

I have polygons in WKT that looks like this

```
POLYGON ((24.8085317 46.8512821, 24.7986952 46.8574619, 24.8088238 46.8664741, 24.8155239 46.8576335, 24.8085317 46.8512821))
```

I would like to calculate the area of this polygon in km².

How do I do this in Python?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It wasn't readily apparent to me how to use @sgillies answer, so here is a more verbose version:

```
import pyproj    
import shapely
import shapely.ops as ops
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
from functools import partial


geom = Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 10), (10, 10), (10, 0), (0, 0)])
geom_area = ops.transform(
    partial(
        pyproj.transform,
        pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:4326'),
        pyproj.Proj(
            proj='aea',
            lat_1=geom.bounds[1],
            lat_2=geom.bounds[3]
        )
    ),
    geom)

# Print the area in m^2
print(geom_area.area)
```

Answer (score 20):

It looks like your coordinates are longitude and latitude.

Use Shapely's [`shapely.ops.transform`](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#shapely.ops.transform) function to transform the polygon to [projected equal area coordinates](http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/proj_list/albers_equal_area_conic.html) and then take the area.

```
python
import pyproj
from functools import partial

geom_aea = transform(
partial(
    pyproj.transform,
    pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:4326'),
    pyproj.Proj(
        proj='aea',
        lat1=geom.bounds[1],
        lat2=geom.bounds[3])),
geom)

print(geom_aea.area)
# Output in m^2: 1083461.9234313113
```

Answer (score 10):

The other answers seem to be correct, except that at some point, the lat1 and lat2 parameters in the pyproj code were renamed with underscores: lat_1 and lat_2 (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55259718/1538758).

```
import pyproj    
import shapely
import shapely.ops as ops
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
from functools import partial


geom = Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 10), (10, 10), (10, 0), (0, 0)])
geom_area = ops.transform(
    partial(
        pyproj.transform,
        pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:4326'),
        pyproj.Proj(
            proj='aea',
            lat_1=geom.bounds[1],
            lat_2=geom.bounds[3])),
    geom)

# Print the area in m^2
print geom_area.area
```

Answer (score 8):

Calculate a geodesic area, which is very accurate and only requires an ellipsoid (not a projection). This can be done with pyproj 2.3.0 or later.

```py
from pyproj import Geod
from shapely import wkt

# specify a named ellipsoid
geod = Geod(ellps="WGS84")

poly = wkt.loads('''\
POLYGON ((24.8085317 46.8512821, 24.7986952 46.8574619,
24.8088238 46.8664741, 24.8155239 46.8576335, 24.8085317 46.8512821))''')

area = abs(geod.geometry_area_perimeter(poly)[0])

print('# Geodesic area: {:12.3f} m²'.format(area))
print('#                {:12.3f} km²'.format(area/1e6))

# Geodesic area:  1083466.869 m²
#                       1.083 km²
```

[`abs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs) is used to return only positive areas. A negative area may be returned depending on the winding direction of the polygon.

Answer (score 6):

I've stumbled across "area" which seems simpler to use:

https://pypi.org/project/area/

For example:

```
from area import area

obj = {'type':'Polygon','coordinates':[[[24.8085317,46.8512821], [24.7986952,46.8574619], [24.8088238,46.8664741], [24.8155239,46.8576335], [24.8085317,46.8512821]]]}

area_m2 = area(obj)

area_km2 = area_m2 / 1e+6
print ('area m2:' + str(area_m2))
print ('area km2:' + str(area_km2))
```

... returns:

area m2:1082979.880942425

area km2:1.082979880942425

Answer (score 2):

I've found that the projected option is a bit too slow for my use so I did some digging and found a javascript lib from Mapbox called [cheap-ruler](https://github.com/mapbox/cheap-ruler). The "cheap" in the name is intended to imply that this algorithm isn't intended to return the right answer, but simply a good enough one.

Below is my copy and paste port of the area function to work with a shapely geom. My port doesn't remove area for holes, but it could be updated to do so.

```py
import math

def area(geom):
    ## Setup from:
    ## https://github.com/mapbox/cheap-ruler/blob/48ad4768a52dc176b01494d090cce19f02c7afdd/index.js#L71-L82
    RE = 6378.137
    RAD = math.pi / 180
    FE = 1 / 298.257223563
    E2 = FE * (2 - FE)

    lat = geom.centroid.y
    m = RAD * RE * 1000
    coslat = math.cos(lat * RAD);

    w2 = 1 / (1 - E2 * (1 - coslat * coslat))
    w = math.sqrt(w2)
    kx = m * w * coslat
    ky = m * w * w2 * (1 - E2)

    ## Area calc from:
    ## https://github.com/mapbox/cheap-ruler/blob/48ad4768a52dc176b01494d090cce19f02c7afdd/index.js#L185-L197
    ring = geom.exterior.coords

    sumVal = 0
    j = 0
    l = len(ring)
    k = l - 1
    while j < l:
        sumVal += wrap(ring[j][0] - ring[k][0]) * (ring[j][1] + ring[k][1])
        k = j
        j += 1

    return (abs(sumVal) / 2) * kx * ky;

def wrap(deg):
    while deg < -180:
        deg += 360
    while deg > 180:
        deg -= 360
    return deg
```

Answer (score 2):

As you probably use this in a loop for many geometries you can get faster transformations by using modern Proj as intended and by not recreating static objects like the initial CRS:

```
from pyproj import Transformer, transform, CRS
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import shapely.ops as ops

geom = Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 10), (10, 10), (10, 0), (0, 0)])

crs_4326 = CRS.from_epsg(4326)

transformer = Transformer.from_crs(
    crs_4326,
    CRS(proj='aea', 
        lat_1=geom.bounds[1],
        lat_2=geom.bounds[3]
    )
)

geom_area = ops.transform(transformer.transform, geom)
```

is about twice as fast for me if you measure the setup of the transformer and the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

@bugmenot123 answer is not correct you need to change code to otherwise you get wrong area you will have switched long,lat ....

```py
        transformer = Transformer.from_crs(
            CRS_WGS_84,
            CRS(proj='aea',
                lat_1=shape.bounds[1],
                lat_2=shape.bounds[3]
                ),
            always_xy=True
        )
```