# Calculating area of geometry using Geopandas?

Tags: python, geopandas, calculate-geometry

Is there an easy way in geopandas to calcuate polygon areas after an intersection analysis?
I am switching from ArcGIS to open source and try to translate my code.
In ArcGIS I used:

```
arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management("df1", "AREA", Area_Unit="HECTARES")
```

Comment: Did you try the solution in this question? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218450/getting-polygon-areas-using-geopandas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the area property of the geometry column:

```
import geopandas as gpd
df = gpd.read_file('/home/bera/someshapefile.shp')
df['area'] = df.geometry.area #/10000 for hectares
```