# Is transformation using square metres or kilometres (3857/32633)?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas, area

I am using Geopandas to compute population per km2. However, I don't know if this transformation is using meters or kilometers.

```
gacs_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(acs_df.merge(census_gdf2, on="geo_12", how="inner").drop_duplicates(subset='geo_12'), crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'})
gacs_df = gacs_df.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3857'})
gacs_df["area"] = gacs_df['geometry'].area/ 10**6
gacs_df= gacs_df.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:32633'})
gacs_df["area"] = gacs_df['geometry'].area/ 10**6
```

I am replicating the code from [Getting polygon areas using GeoPandas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218450/getting-polygon-areas-using-geopandas).

Answer (score 2):

Both [EPSG:3857](https://epsg.io/3857) and [EPSG:32633](https://epsg.io/32633) have units in **metres**. If you divide the resulting area by 10^6 (=1,000,000), you get square kilometres (km²).