# How to determine a polygon's area in a metric unit?

Tags: coordinate-system, geopandas, area, shape-area

I have created a square grid and I would like to figure out the *real world* area of each polygon in a metric unit e.q. square metres via `GeoDataFrame.area`.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

# Latitude (y)
lat_min = -90
lat_max = 90

# Longtidue (x)
lon_min = -180
lon_max = 180

# Edge length
side_length = 0.5

# List to which we will append the polygons
temp_polygons = []

for y in range(int(abs(lat_min-lat_max)/side_length)):

    for x in range(int(abs(lon_min-lon_max)/side_length)):
        
        x_start = lon_min + x * side_length
        y_start = lat_min + y * side_length
        
        bottom_left_x = x_start 
        bottom_left_y = y_start
        
        bottom_right_x = x_start + side_length
        bottom_right_y = y_start
        
        top_right_x = x_start + side_length
        top_right_y = y_start + side_length
        
        top_left_x = x_start
        top_left_y = y_start + side_length
        
        # Append polygon to list
        temp_polygons.append(
            # Polygon
            Polygon([
                # Bottom-left
                (bottom_left_x,bottom_left_y),
                # Bottom-right
                (bottom_right_x,bottom_right_y),
                # Top-left
                (top_right_x,top_right_y),
                # Top-right
                (top_left_x,top_left_y)
                ])
            )

# Turn list of polygons into GeoSeries
temp_polygons = gpd.GeoSeries(temp_polygons)

# Turn GeoSeries into GeoDataFrame
raster = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': temp_polygons})

# Add coordinate reference system
raster.crs = {"init":"epsg:4326"}

# Change projection
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator_projection#EPSG:3857
raster['geometry'] = (
    raster['geometry'].to_crs({'init': 'EPSG:3857'})
    )

# Get area
raster['area'] = raster.area
```

First, the geometries are as follows:

[image]

However, after applying ...

```py
# Change projection
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator_projection#EPSG:3857
raster['geometry'] = (
    raster['geometry'].to_crs({'init': 'EPSG:3857'})
    )
```

... there are a lot of inf values and hence the cells' area is `nan`:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Did I select a wrong CRS? How can I determine the area of each grid cell in a metric unit?

---

Edit:

[This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/166421/97137) answer seems to work for me. However, with ~25 iterations/second it's rather slow (~3 hours for ~260,000 rows). It's not prohibitively slow but there must be a quicker solution.

Comment: This may help you: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127607/area-in-km-from-polygon-of-coordinates

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This answer seems to work: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/166421/97137; However, it's rather slow. ~25 iterations per second. That's too slow for my >250,000 rows.

Comment: Tangential comment: Do you remember why you thought that EPSG:3857 would give you actual meters? I would love to fix the web on that misleading thought so if it was a website or something, I'd be interested.

Comment: While EPSG:3857 won't give you useful areal measurements, are you sure your axes are correct? I get no NaNs with pyproj==3.1.0 and geopandas==0.9.0.

Comment: @bugmenot123 Thank you for your comments! Sorry but I cannot recall where I stumbled upon that information. It may have even been Stackexchange but I cannot find it anymore. Regarding the 2nd comment I am not a hundred percent sure what you mean. I provided all the code in the minimal working example.

Comment: Cheers! Newer versions of proj (used for transformations) are more strict when it comes to x/y vs lon/lat axes. Try switching your longitude and latitude values, that might give you working transformations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to calculate lat/long cell area in m^2 without any transformation as long as they are regular grid cells. In other words the polygons must be squares where each side is a latitudinal or longitudinal line. From the article [Santini et al. 2010](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=15425800687232996973)

It's quite fast. It did the ~260,000 cells in your `raster` data in ~10 seconds on my small desktop computer.

```
timeit.timeit(lambda: raster.geometry.apply(lat_lon_cell_area), number=1)
10.299032560084015

raster.shape
(259200, 2)
```

I confirmed the values by writing the `raster` grid to a shapefile and then opening it in qgis where I measured some cell areas manually. The two were approximately the same.

```py
from math import radians, sin

def lat_lon_cell_area(lat_lon_grid_cell):
    """
    Calculate the area of a cell, in meters^2, on a lat/lon grid.
    
    This applies the following equation from Santini et al. 2010.
    
    S = (λ_2 - λ_1)(sinφ_2 - sinφ_1)R^2
    
    S = surface area of cell on sphere
    λ_1, λ_2, = bands of longitude in radians
    φ_1, φ_2 = bands of latitude in radians
    R = radius of the sphere
    
    Santini, M., Taramelli, A., & Sorichetta, A. (2010). ASPHAA: A GIS‐Based 
    Algorithm to Calculate Cell Area on a Latitude‐Longitude (Geographic) 
    Regular Grid. Transactions in GIS, 14(3), 351-377.
    https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1467-9671.2010.01200.x

    Parameters
    ----------
    lat_lon_grid_cell
        A shapely box with coordinates on the lat/lon grid

    Returns
    -------
    float
        The cell area in meters^2

    """
    
    # mean earth radius - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius#Mean_radius
    AVG_EARTH_RADIUS_METERS = 6371008.8
    
    west, south, east, north = lat_lon_grid_cell.bounds

    west = radians(west)
    east = radians(east)
    south = radians(south)
    north = radians(north)
    
    return (east - west) * (sin(north) - sin(south)) * (AVG_EARTH_RADIUS_METERS**2)


#------
# Example using a 2 degree lat/lon grid
#------

import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import box

# Latitude (y)
lat_min = -90
lat_max = 90

# Longitude (x)
lon_min = -180
lon_max = 180

# Edge length
side_length = 2

all_lats, all_lons = np.meshgrid(
    np.arange(lat_min, lat_max, side_length),
    np.arange(lon_min, lon_max, side_length)
    )

polygons = []
for lon, lat in zip(all_lons.flatten(), all_lats.flatten()):
    polygons.append(
        box(lon, lat, lon+side_length, lat+side_length)
        )

raster = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': gpd.GeoSeries(polygons)})

raster['cell_area'] = raster.geometry.apply(lat_lon_cell_area)
```

Comment: Thank you for your superb answer! It seems to work perfectly fine. I checked `raster['cell_area'].sum()` and it deviates by only 1% (`510063456035226.2 / 510065880972871.75 = 0.9999952458344382`) from the result I cross-linked in my answer (I guess the deviation is caused by e.g. post-digit differences in e.g. the earth radius). But your approach is much much quicker! ... perfect answer! Thanks!